# French equivalent of the Facebook term "seen-zoned"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

I just picked up this Facebook-exclusive(?) term "seen-zoned" or "seen zone". I've asked my girlfriend who uses Facebook about a possible French equivalent, but I'm still none the wiser.

Another Facebook term "[unfriend](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unfriend)" seems to have already made its way into a dictionary entry, but not for "seen-zoned".

> You courageously click on your crush’s name and type a nerve-wracking ‘Hey, how’s it going?’ You wait for the little check mark to appear, the one that tells you that the person that you want to acknowledge you has actually read your message. And then you wait again. You check your Facebook over and over. You sneak peeks on your phone at work. You double check to see that the little check mark has actually appeared.
>
> You go from thinking: ‘Maybe they’re just busy’ to ‘Why aren’t they responding?” and after a day or two or even a week, it becomes clear. They’re not going to respond. They’ve seen your message and they’re leaving it unanswered like a high-five left hanging in the air. You’ve been ***seen-zoned***.
>
> I’m guilty of the ***seen zone*** myself.

Comment: Given that nobody would know or understand this term in English without an extended explanation, looking for a French equivalent seems somewhat futile.

Comment: Congrats on the 10k! I had the honor to give the final upvote myself haha

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ah, thanks! I've been just below the 10K threshold for the last 3 months or so, hovering around 9990. Looking back, I've been around on French SE for almost as long as you have, eh? I've come a long way over the last two years, starting from "un, deux, trois ...". :)

Comment: Après avoir lu la question, les réponses et l'ensemble des commentaires je ne comprends toujours pas ce que ce terme signifie. Vraiment incroyable et consternant.

Comment: @0ne1 Dans le contexte de Facebook, cela signifie que ton message privé envoyé à quelqu'un porte la mention "Vu" (mention qui apparaît lorsque la personne a, a priori, lu ton message) mais que cette personne ne t'a jamais répondu. Tu es passé dans la catégorie "message vu mais pas répondu", à savoir que cette personne ne s'intéresse pas à toi. Terme semblable plus connu : friend zone (quand quelqu'un qui t'intéresse te considère comme un "simple" ami).

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens there is no exact equivalent, after all we use "friend zone", of course it's slang directly from English and not everyone understand it, only "young" people. I'm pretty sure some people use "seen zone" in France. I mean without knowing the term, I instantly understood it and I'm sure I could have used it without knowing it already existed.

Answer (score 2):

Ce terme n'a évidemment pas pour l'heure de traduction française exacte.

Les habitués semblent, pour exprimer ce fait, recourir à un anglicisme entré dans la langue française aux temps de la télévision : *zapper* !

- *You have been seen-zoned => tu t'es fait zapper*

Le déverbal *zappeur* existe aussi. Il pourrait alors désigner le *guilty of the seen zone.*

EDIT : Full credits to jlliagre in commentaires ci-contre : On pourrait aussi utiliser l'expression *prendre un vent*. *Tu t'es pris un vent*

ndaCOSwt : Ma réédition ici n'a évidemment que pour objet de ne pas donner à jlliagre l'impression de... s'être fait zapper... heuu! de s'être pris un vent... well! leave him with the impression of being seen-zoned! ;)

Comment: On pourrait aussi évoquer : *tu t'es pris un vent*.

Comment: @jlliagre : Oui mais, (et peut-être n'est-ce que moi), j'entends un petit coté vexatoire dans l'expression que tu cites. Or je n'entends cette intention vexatoire ni dans seen-zone ni dans zapper. Mais encore une fois peut-être n'est-ce que moi.

Comment: Un *high-five left hanging in the air*, ça ressemble beaucoup à un vent...

Answer (score 1):

The currently winning expression seems to be *laisser en vu* (“leave in seen”, not to be confused with *laisser en vue* “keep in sight”) as anecdotally evidenced by [a Twitter search](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22laiss%C3%A9%20en%20vu%22) and a [Google test](https://www.google.com/search?&q="laisser+en+vu"&oq="laisser+en+vu") (around 27k hits as of 2019-11-04).
A relatively notorious example would be that memetic fake screenshot.

[image: screenshot with text “Tu m'a laissé en vu sans faire exprès […]”]